# div with iframe in it, display none

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where I am displaying a iframe from another page. I want that iframe to be display:none at load and become visible onClick. The issue is, I can get it to work if the div is visible at load. If it is hidden at load, the onclick doesnt work properly.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
    </script>


<div style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <p>Dayton, Ohio Menu Coming Soon. It can be viewed currently at <a href="https://www.leafly.com/dispensary-info/pure-ohio-wellness" target="_blank" style="color:green">here</a></p>
            <p><a onClick="myFunction()">Springfield, Ohio Menu</a></p>
            <div>
            <div id="myDIV" style="display: none">
        <div id="leafly-menu">
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
            </div>
            <script src="https://www.leafly.com/public/global/js/dispensarymanager/embed.js"></script>
<script>var pymParent = pym.Parent('leafly-menu', 'https://www.leafly.com/embed/menu2/pure-ohio-wellness---springfield', {});</script>
        </div>
        <div style="overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 975px;display: none;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="https://www.leafly.com/dispensary-info/pure-ohio-wellness---springfield" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -36px; height: 1012px; margin-top: -486px; width: 1050px;">
</iframe>
</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Russell I created a fiddle for you. Check this link. I think this is the solution for you. https://jsfiddle.net/aryalsan/9bm8L6gv/. I ma using jquery.

Comment: Thank you. Can you add a second menu to this? you can use the same one for now. I need to create links for 2 different locations to display the menus. The second location is in Dayton, Ohio

Comment: Please check the fiddle again, I updated with the two links.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9b15gw0f/

Answer (score 0):

I think the functionality you're looking for here can be solved with the visibility:hidden tag, as I've had similar experienced with the "display:none" css property.

Definitely worth another google for differences between the two, but the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display) snippet here seems to summarize things pretty well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not solve my issue because I need to have a menu for the new location and with visibility : hidden, it still holds the space on the page. If someone wants to see the menu for the second location, they would have to scroll down the page till the hidden div is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily display the elements inside the Div using the `click()` function of jQuery. You need to include the jQuery CDN or jQuery file to run the jQuery scripts.

```js
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#showMe").click(function () {
          $("#myDIV").show();
        })
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div style="margin-top:30px;">
      <h2>Menu</h2>
      <p>Dayton, Ohio Menu Coming Soon. It can be viewed currently at <a href="https://www.leafly.com/dispensary-info/pure-ohio-wellness" target="_blank" style="color:green">here</a></p>
          <p><a id = "showMe" href="#">Springfield, Ohio Menu</a></p>
          <div id="myDIV" style="display: none">
            <div >
              <div id="leafly-menu">
              </div>
              <div style="text-align:center;">
              </div>
              <script src="https://www.leafly.com/public/global/js/dispensarymanager/embed.js"></script>
              <script>var pymParent = pym.Parent('leafly-menu', 'https://www.leafly.com/embed/menu2/pure-ohio-wellness---springfield', {});</script>
            </div>
            <div style="overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 975px;">
              <iframe scrolling="no" src="https://www.leafly.com/dispensary-info/pure-ohio-wellness---springfield" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -36px; height: 1012px; margin-top: -486px; width: 1050px;">
              </iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

I have updated the Fiddle with the two menus.
[https://jsfiddle.net/9b15gw0f/](https://jsfiddle.net/aryalsan/9bm8L6gv/10/)